# Google Apps Script Triggers not firing

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

My Triggers no longer work.  I have two different google sheets with triggers setup.  One sheet has a daily trigger that is set to fire between 9-10am.   The other sheet has two triggers, one fires on a form submit and the second trigger fires on change.  These had been working fine for a solid year before they up and stopped working a week or two ago.

For both of the google sheets, I have tried deleting and re-adding the triggers.  For the one that has the daily timer, I have tried changing the time of day around also.  No luck on them firing own their own.  If I go to the Run Menu and run the function manually it works fine.  I'd rather avoid having to create new google sheets as links to these sheets are published to users in my domain and are in production.

ie.

```
function updateScores()
{
  Logger.log("Function started");

/*  
all of my code here.... 
*/

}
```

When I manually run the function I see the "Function started" message in the logs along with all my other Logger.log statements I have throughout the code.  Calculations are done correctly, emails sent, etc.  The code itself works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've seen a couple of issues regarding triggers not working posted just recently in google-apps-script-issues tracker - [Issue 6226](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6226&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) and the latest is [Issue 6244](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6244&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner).

As advised in this SO post - [Google app script trigger not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701382/google-app-script-trigger-not-working), after checking the logs which you already have done and as you mentioned "The code itself works fine", you may post the issue in [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) .